# NodeJS/Browser Cross-Development

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, amd, commonjs

I'm working on a library that targets both browsers and NodeJS applications. Modules use AMD convention which is theorically flexible enough to map pretty much any situation today. Source files are then to be converted with tools to be distributed for different platforms - again browsers and NodeJS.
By the way, there's a wonderful tool called [uRequire](http://urequire.org/) to help with that but I'm still not sure what my best option is, so I'm asking here for relevant experience.

Here are the files hierarchy I have:

```
- bower_components/
    - eventemitter2/ ...
    - lodash/ ...

- source/
    - library/
        - lodash.js -> ../../bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.js
        - EventEmitter.js -> ../../bower_components/eventemitter2/lib/eventemitter2.js

    - Observable.js:

        define(["lodash", "EventEmitter"], function(Utility, EventEmitter) {
            function Observable(options) { ... };

            return Observable;
        });
```

At the end, the big difference between browser and NodeJS sides is:

- Browser-side: `EventEmitter` implementation simply is the `eventemitter2` browser module that is configured to be "library/EventEmitter";
- NodeJS-side: `EventEmitter` is gotten from `require("events").EventEmitter`, with `events` being a native package, not a local file or module;

So, my question is: how can I have that `Observable` object work with NodeJS without massive tinkering? What I'm not sure about how I can make the `EventEmitter` implementation available to my module since it is not a local module (as such I cannot write any paths mapping) and moreover it is not directly the module itself we'll use but the "EventEmitter" property of it...

Any help/thinking would be appreciated. I believe that many have run in similar situations and I'd be curious to know what they have to say!

Comment: Consider using Browserify.  It has browser modules compatible with the Node.js modules.

Comment: That's a pretty short answer... :)
How dow you handle the case of different implementations like XMLHttpRequest in one side and "http" module in the other, for example?

Comment: Those situations are much trickier, and need to be handled in your code.  There is no silver bullet though.  Browserify gets  you most of the way there (all of the way there in some modules).

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard - I think you can safely stick with uRequire (I am the author). Perhaps you can use an intermediate EventEmitter module that checks [runtimeinfo](http://urequire.org/masterdefaultsconfig.coffee#build.runtimeinfo) and loads / returns the right EventEmitter object. So you can use EventEmitter without thinking about it. Expect a full answer within the next few days!

Answer (score 1):

[uRequire](http://urequire.org) makes it trivial to use [runtimeInfo](http://urequire.org/masterdefaultsconfig.coffee#build.runtimeinfo) and selectivelly load alternative dependencies at runtime (*you can always choose to have alternative builds and [replace deps with alternative/mocks](http://urequire.org/masterdefaultsconfig.coffee#bundle.dependencies.replace) at build time, if you dont want to write selective code like this*).

[Runtime info](http://urequire.org/masterdefaultsconfig.coffee#build.runtimeinfo) works the same in all templates, including [UMD](http://urequire.org/umd-template) and [combined](http://urequire.org/combined-template), so either if executing on:

- **nodejs**
- **browser** with an AMD loader like [requirejs](http://www.requirejs.org/) or
- **browser** with the plain `</script>` tag,

you can choose what each module dependency means in each case dynamically, using `__isAMD`, `__isNode` & `__isWeb` runtime variables.

What you need is :

```
- bower_components/
    - eventemitter2/ ...
    - lodash/ ...
    - requirejs/ ...

- source/
    - library/
        - EventEmitter.js     
        - Observable.js:
```

where `Observable.js` is for example

```
define(["lodash", "EventEmitter"], function(_, EventEmitter) {
  function Observable(options) { this.myOptions = options };

  Observable.EventEmitter = EventEmitter;
  Observable._ = _;
  return Observable;
});
```

and `EventEmitter.js` is :

```
define(function(){
  var EventEmitter2;
  if (__isNode) {
    return require("events").EventEmitter;
  } else {
    if (__isAMD) {
      return EventEmitter2 = require("eventemitter2"); 
    } else if (__isWeb) {
      return window.EventEmitter2;
    }
  }
});
```

** notes** :

- You don't need to worry about `"events"` trying to load on the AMD side, cause its a [known node dep (otherwise you would need to list it)](http://urequire.org/masterdefaultsconfig.coffee#bundle.dependencies.node).
- `EventEmitter2 = require(...)` is needed to *establish* the [inference of exported dependency identifier](http://urequire.org/types-and-derive#inferred-binding-idenifiers) `EventEmitter2` to `window`. The last case, Web/Script uses `window.EventEmitter2` thanks to this! Alternatively you can [list it in depsVars](http://urequire.org/masterdefaultsconfig.coffee#bundle.dependencies.depsvars).

Then with the following [grunt-urequire](https://github.com/aearly/grunt-urequire) config (in coffeescript):

```
module.exports = gruntFunction = (grunt) ->

  grunt.initConfig gruntConfig =
    urequire:
      library:
        path: "source/library"
        dstPath: "build/UMD"
        runtimeInfo: ['EventEmitter'] # dont need it in other files
        template: 'UMDplain'

      combined:
        derive: 'library'
        main: 'Observable'
        dependencies: exports: root: {'Observable': 'Obs'}
        dstPath: "build/almond/Observable.js"
        template: 'combined'

  grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-urequire"
```

you have two builds:

A) `library` : with separate UMD files, where you can run eg from `source\test\load_node.js` :

```
var Observable = require("../../build/UMD/Observable");
console.log(Observable.EventEmitter);
```

or from the browser (`source/test/Loader_unoptimized_AMD.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>test crossdev: RequireJs, UMD</title></head>
  <body>Check console!</body>

  <script src="../../bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
  <script>
     require.config ({
      baseUrl: '../../build/almond',
      paths: {
        lodash: "../../bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.min",
        eventemitter2: "../../bower_components/eventemitter2/lib/eventemitter2"
      }
    });

    require(["Observable" ], function(Observable){
      console.log(Observable);
      console.log(Observable.EventEmitter);
    });

  </script>
</html>
```

and

B) `combined` with all files inlined & having its own mini-loader ([almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond)) that works on nodejs, Web/AMD and Web/Script. Running from `source/test/Loader_almondJs_plainScript.html` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>test crossdev: plain script, combined/almond</title></head>
  <body>Check console!</body>

  <script src="../../bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../bower_components/eventemitter2/lib/eventemitter2.js"></script>
  <script src="../../build/almond/Observable.js"></script>

  <script>
    console.log(window.Obs);
    console.log(window.Obs.EventEmitter);
  </script>
</html>
```

or using RequireJs as AMD loader (`source/test/Loader_almondJs_AMD.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>test crossdev: RequireJs, combined/almond</title></head>
  <body>Check console!</body>

  <script src="../../bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
  <script>
     require.config ({
      baseUrl: '../../build/almond',
      paths: {
        lodash: "../../bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.min",
        eventemitter2: "../../bower_components/eventemitter2/lib/eventemitter2"
      }
    });

    require(["Observable" ], function(Observable){
      console.log(Observable);
      console.log(Observable.EventEmitter);
    });

  </script>
</html>
```

You can see the test project in https://github.com/anodynos/nodejs-browser-cross-development